# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value, while calling httppost via ajax post

Tags: asp.net-web-api

[image]

I am trying to receive a post request with some json string

```
var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: JSON.stringify(fileData),
              url: "http://hercules/JsonTest/api/Getjson/sendData",
              contentType: contentType,
              processData: false,
              error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("failure: " + qXHR.status + ":" + textStatus + errorThrown);
              },
              success : function(data) {
                  alert("Success : " + data);
              }
          });
```

and in my webapi

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.ActionName("sendData")]
        public string sendData([FromBody] string jsonString)
        {
            logData("Entering SendData : " + jsonString);
            return "Success";
        }
```

But, my jsonString posted is not received in the webapi. it is throwing error Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

What could be the reason.
I was testing the code directly in my visual studio and the same was working fine. but once i published the same in machine, and tried to access via a jsFiddle, then the string is showing empty.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved.
In my ajax post request i modified

**data: JSON.stringify(fileData),** 
to
**data: '=' + fileData,**

With equal to added, the data is correctly received in HTTPPOST method of MVC.

Thanks...